# Mostrar resultados de query mysql horizontalmente

Tags: mysql

tengo una tabla llamada "revisiones" en mysql, que tiene su campo id, id_producto,fecha(datetime). Esta tabla tiene solo un registro por mes y necesito que me arroje el resultado de la consulta hacia el lado en vez de en filas hacia abajo, es decir :

```
  select * from revisiones
```

=

id,id_producto,fecha(Mes1),fecha(Mes2),fecha(Mes3),etc

hay alguna manera de hacer esto?

Comment: Lo puedes hacer con GROUP_CONCAT. Pero me parece extraño ese diseño... _Esta tabla tiene solo un registro por mes_ ¿Significa que en tu tabla hay varias filas donde se repite el id_producto? Si es así tendrías que pensar la organización de tu tabla de otra manera.

Comment: o sea, tiene un registro por mes para cada id_producto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto debería funcionarte.

Podrás ver que se crea una columna llamada **fechas** usando [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d83ef/2). Cada valor tiene un separador, en este caso he usado `|`. Si quieres tratar cada valor como una columna individual lo puedes hacer con un split. Si sólo quieres el mes, MySQL tiene funciones para obtener solamente el mes de una fecha dada.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d83ef/2)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE productos
    (`producto_id` int, `producto_nom` varchar(70))
;

INSERT INTO productos
    (`producto_id`, `producto_nom`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Pan'),
    (2, 'Vino'),
    (3, 'Aceite')
;

CREATE TABLE revisiones
    (`id` int, `producto_id` int, `fecha` date)
;

INSERT INTO revisiones
    (`id`, `producto_id`, `fecha`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, '2017-01-10'),
    (2, 1, '2017-02-22'),
    (3, 1, '2017-03-25'),
    (4, 2, '2017-01-20'),
    (5, 2, '2017-02-28'),
    (6, 2, '2017-02-28'),
    (7, 3, '2017-01-06'),
    (8, 3, '2017-02-07'),
    (9, 3, '2017-03-08')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
  p.producto_nom, GROUP_CONCAT(r.fecha SEPARATOR '|') as fechas
FROM
  revisiones r
LEFT JOIN 
  productos p ON r.producto_id=p.producto_id
GROUP BY p.producto_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d83ef/2/0)**:

```
| producto_nom |                           fechas |
|--------------|----------------------------------|
|          Pan | 2017-03-25|2017-02-22|2017-01-10 |
|         Vino | 2017-02-28|2017-02-28|2017-01-20 |
|       Aceite | 2017-02-07|2017-01-06|2017-03-08 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(r.fecha SEPARATOR '|') as fechas
FROM
  revisiones r
GROUP BY r.producto_id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6d83ef/2/1)**:

```
|                           fechas |
|----------------------------------|
| 2017-01-10|2017-02-22|2017-03-25 |
| 2017-01-20|2017-02-28|2017-02-28 |
| 2017-01-06|2017-02-07|2017-03-08 |
```

Comment: gracias por responder, no me resulto. Me obligo a poner todos los campos de la tabla productos en group by y mostro los resultados normamente, es decir hacia abajo y sin seprarador

Comment: @daniel2017 De acuerdo a lo que he entendido, en tu tabla revisiones tienes varias filas con las columnas siguientes `producto_id` y `fecha`. Si es así y lo único que te interesa es el id del producto y la fecha, haciendo esto debería funcionar: `SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(fecha SEPARATOR '|') as fechas
FROM
  revisiones GROUP BY producto_id` Adapta los nombres de columnas a los de tu tabla. Te dará como resultado una columna parecida a la de la derecha del ejemplo. Simplemente quise ponerte un ejemplo más completo, mostrando los nombres de productos.

Comment: gracia ya me resulto, pero sabes si esos valores separador por el "|" se pueden tratar como campos individuales en php?

Comment: @daniel2017- Observa la respuesta ahora, la Query 2 y sus resultados.

Comment: @daniel2017- Para tratarlos como valores individuales en PHP puedes usar `explode`. Ejemplo:  `$datos = explode("|", $datosencolumnafechas);` eso creará un array con cada valor usando como separador el `|`, por lo que en `$datos[0]` tendrás el 1er valor... y así sucesivamente. Ver: http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php También puedes leer todos los valores de `$datos` usando un bucle, es más seguro.