# ¿Cómo almacenar determinados campos de una consulta sql en un array con PHP?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Cómo puedo guardar en un array los valores de las categorías (*excelente, muy_bien, bien, regular, mal*) por cada criterio, para poder ordenarlo, contarlos y despues pueda calcular la mediana de por cada criterio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ya tienes una conexión con tu base de datos? ya has intentado algun query?

Comment: si ya tengo mi conexion a la base de datos, incluso esa misma tabla la confeccioné y la muestro en una página, lo que necesito es poder guardar los valores por cada criterio en un array, para poder hacer este otro código: 

sort($totalfila);
$count=count($totalfila);
$middleval = floor(($count-1)/2);
if($count % 2){
 $median = $totalfila[$middleval];
 }else{
  $low = $totalfila[$middleval];
  $high = $totalfila[$middleval+1];
  $median = (($low+$high)/2);
 }
 echo $median;

Comment: Mira esta [guia](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: agrega toda esa informacion en la pregunta, y el codigo que tengas que sea relevante.

Comment: Tú puedes valerte de `GROUP_CONCAT` para obtener valores de varias columnas en una sola, usando un separador como este `|` u otro. Luego puedes crear un array por programación (php) con cada una de esas columnas usando `explode`. Incluso, si las diferentes filas de la imagen que presentas corresponden a un solo registro, las puedes mostrar **todas** en una sola fila mediante `GROUP_CONCAT` combinado con `GROUP BY`. [Mira una respuesta que lo hace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/58385/29967), sería aplicar ese mismo criterio en tu contexto. Supongo que lo que quieres es algo parecido.

Comment: gracias a todos por ayudar de alguna forma, ya tengo la solución al problema.