# Poner cada fila obtenida en columnas independientes. MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Hago esta consulta:

```
SELECT idFormacion FROM alumnos_formacion
```

Y obtengo esto:

```
|idFormacion|
-------------
      6
      9
      12
```

Mi duda es si se puede hacer una consulta para poner en columnas independientes cada fila obtenida.

```
|idFormacion1| |idFormacion2| |idFormacion3|
-------------  -------------  ------------- 
      6              9              12
```

No se si esto será posible.

Comment: Puedes usar `GROUP_CONCAT` combinado con `GROUP BY`, en caso de que esas filas tuvieran algún valor que las agrupe, aunque sea en otra tabla relacionada, no importa. Pero en vez de tres, o más columnas, obtendrías una sola columna con los datos separador por algún caracter. Luego por programación los puedes obtener como datos individuales. [Aquí puedes ver un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/82380/29967), y aquí [tienes otro ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/58385/29967).

Comment: Gracias por responder @A.Cedano pero no me he enterado muy bien con los ejemplo que pones.

Comment: Mario, ¿hay alguna columna que sea común a esos valores, sea en la propia tabla, sea en otra tabla (por ejemplo el id del alumno), para poder ponerte un ejemplo basado en tus datos? Con la información tan escueta que das en la pregunta es imposible poner un ejemplo mínimo. @Kiko_L en MySQL no existe `PIVOT`. Esa pregunta/respuesta es propia de SQL Server.

Comment: Cierto, no me había fijado que hablaba de mySQL. Borro el comentario.

Comment: Supongamos que la tabla se relaciona con otra tabla `tabla_alumnos`. Entonces escribirías la consulta así: `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(idFormacion SEPARATOR '|')  formaciones FROM tabla_formaciones f INNER JOIN  tabla_alumnos a ON f.id_alumno=a.id_alumno GROUP BY f.id_alumno;` El resultado será una columna llamada `formaciones` que agrupará cada id con un separador, algo así: **`6|9|12`**, luego, en PHP puedes hacer un `explode` sobre esa columna y obtener los valores `6,9,12...` y todos los que haya, por separado. La ventaja de esto es que no tienes que crear `n` columnas por cada valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este tipo de formas de mostrar los datos entiendo que es mucho mejor resolverlo en la vista de los datos y no en la lógica SQL, el comentario de @A. Cedano es un buen punto de partida. Sin embargo puede haber casos en que es mandatorio resolverlo desde la consulta en sí. Una forma de hacerlo sería la siguiente:

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN nr=1 THEN IdFormacion ELSE NULL END) 'IdFormacion1',
       MAX(CASE WHEN nr=2 THEN IdFormacion ELSE NULL END) 'IdFormacion2',
       MAX(CASE WHEN nr=3 THEN IdFormacion ELSE NULL END) 'IdFormacion3'
    FROM (SELECT t.IdFormacion, 
                 @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS nr
                 FROM alumnos_formacion t, 
                 (SELECT @rownum := 0) r
          ) f;
```

Veamos:

- La subconsulta inicial, genera una lista numerada de cada una de los `IdFormacion` de `alumnos_formacion`. Esta consulta tiene sentido si solo tenemos formaciones distintas, es decir, si como supongo esta tabla además tiene un `id` de alumno, imagino que la consulta debería hacerse por `alumno`.
- Luego usando el numerador anterior, simplemente ubicamos con la función de agregación `MAX` y un `CASE` cada una de las `formaciones` en la columna indicada.

Importante:

- Es fundamental establecer el máximo de formaciones posibles, si no hay un máximo, lamentablemente vas a tener que establecer uno, ya que una consulta SQL no puede crecer indefinidamente de forma horizontal (hay límites impuestos por el motor)