# Columnas en mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la sigueinte sentencia:

```
SELECT
    REF
FROM
    inv_articulo as a
    INNER JOIN inv_tipoarticulo as t ON a.TIPO_ARTICULO = t.PK_TIPO
    INNER JOIN inv_categoria as c ON c.PK_CATEGORIA = t.FK_CATEGORIA
WHERE
    c.pk_categoria = 7
order by a.ref
```

Me da como resultado lo siguiente:

```
-----------------
      REF 
-----------------
   OFI-0017  | 
-----------------
   OFI-0021  |
```

Lo que deseo hacer es que el resultado me lo dé de la siguinte manera:

```
-----------------
      REF1   |  REF2
-----------------
   OFI-0017  |  OFI-0021 
-----------------
```

Alguna ayuda?

Comment: Posible duplicado https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/58341/mostrar-resultados-de-query-mysql-horizontalmente

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la instrucción pivot: (Añade una nueva columna autoincrement 
llamada **id**)

```
SELECT
    REF
FROM
    inv_articulo as a
    INNER JOIN inv_tipoarticulo as t ON a.TIPO_ARTICULO = t.PK_TIPO
    INNER JOIN inv_categoria as c ON c.PK_CATEGORIA = t.FK_CATEGORIA
    pivot ( max(inv_categoria)
        for id in (1,2,3,4)
          )
WHERE
    c.pk_categoria = 7
order by a.ref
```

De esta forma los resultados saldrán así:

```
-------------------------
      1      |  2
-------------------------
   OFI-0017  |  OFI-0021
```

Comment: Buenas, lo he probado y me dice lo siguiente: `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'pivot( max(inv_categoria))         for pk_articulo in (1,2,3,4)           ) WHER' at line 7`. Lo he probado cambiando en tu código `id` por `pk_articulo`